# inception v3 using tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using a bit of code that is derived from inception v3 as distributed by the Google folks, but it's now complaining that the queue runners used to read the data are deprecated (tf.train.string_input_producer in image_processing.py, and similar).  Apparently I'm supposed to switch to tf.data for this kind of stuff.

Unfortunately, the documentation on tf.data isn't doing much to relieve my concern that I've got too much data to fit in memory, especially given that I want to batch it in a reusable way, etc. I'm confident that the tf.data stuff *can* do this; I just don't know *how* to do it. Can anyone point me to a full example of code that uses tf.data to deal with batches of data that won't all fit in memory?  Ideally, it would simply be an updated version of the inception-v3 code, but I'd be happy to try and work with anything.  Thanks!

Comment: when I first started reading about the tf.data API, I found these few links to be very useful for me outside of the official api documentation:
[Data pipeline tutorial from Stanford](https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data.html)
[mnist with tf data example](http://cjalmeida.net/post/tensorflow-mnist/)
[Input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets)
Hope you find any of these useful!

Comment: Very helpful; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I eventually got this working.  The various documents referenced in the comment on my question had what I needed, and I gradually figured out which parameters passed to queuerunners corresponded to which parameters in the tf.data stuff.

There was one gotcha that took a while for me to sort out.  In the inception implementation, the number of examples used for validation is rounded up to be a multiple of the batch size; presumably the validation set is reshuffled and some examples are used more than once.  (This does not strike me as great practice, but generally the number of validation instances is way larger than the batch size, so only a relative few are double counted.)

In the tf.data stuff, enabling shuffling and reuse is a separate thing and I didn't do it on the validation data.  Then things broke because there weren't enough unique validation instances, and I had to track that down.

I hope this helps the next person with this issue.  Unfortunately, my code has drifted quite far from Inception v3 and I doubt that it would be helpful for me to post my modification.  Thanks!